# Изменение размера формы по вводу значений в Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте,на форме есть `Combobox`(в котором заложен список значений размеров).
По вводу текста и нажатию `Enter`,новое значение добавляется в наш список значений и размеры формы должны сразу изменяться согласно этим значениям.
Границ между двумя значения `*`.
Проблема: по нажатию `Enter` размеры формы не изменяют,помогите решить.Заранее спасибо.

```
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter&&comboBox1.Text.IndexOf('*')!=-1&&comboBox1.Text.Length>=7)
        {
            if (comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(comboBox1.Text) == -1)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.Text);
                Items.Add(comboBox1.Text);
            }
            this.Height =int.Parse(comboBox1.Text.Substring(0, comboBox1.Text.Length - comboBox1.Text.IndexOf('*')));
            this.Width=int.Parse(comboBox1.Text.Substring(comboBox1.Text.IndexOf('*') + 1, comboBox1.Text.Length - 1 - comboBox1.Text.IndexOf('*')));
        }
```

Comment: Items - лист,хранящий значения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил, не правильно задавал размеры.

```
        private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter&&comboBox1.Text.IndexOf('*')!=-1&&comboBox1.Text.Length>=7)
        {
            if (comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(comboBox1.Text) == -1)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.Text);
                Items.Add(comboBox1.Text);
            }
            this.Width =int.Parse(comboBox1.Text.Substring(0,comboBox1.Text.IndexOf('*')));
            this.Height=int.Parse(comboBox1.Text.Substring(comboBox1.Text.IndexOf('*') + 1, comboBox1.Text.Length - 1 - comboBox1.Text.IndexOf('*')));
        }
    }
```